# Getting 403 forbidden when using the Google Sheets API and a service account

Tags: java, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I have an application that is using a service account (because it runs from a cron job so I can't have it authorize through a user in a browser). Here's how I create the sheets service:

```
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "my app";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

static {
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

private static Credential authorize() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("key.json"), HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY);
    credential = credential.createScoped(SCOPES);
    return credential;
}

static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    Credential credential = authorize();

    return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
}
```

Every time I run it, I get a "com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden" error. Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: did you grant the service account access to the file?

Comment: Thanks for your response! By that, you mean that I added the service account email address as an editor on the file? If so - yes.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm having the same issue and I have given the service account access to the sheet .