# 403 Forbidden Error from google API Javascript client

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-api-js-client

I am getting `403 Forbidden Error` from google API Javascript client. Following is my code:

```js
gapi.load('client', function () {
    console.log('gapi.client loaded.');
    var discoveryUrl = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4';
    gapi.client.load(discoveryUrl).then(function () {
        console.log('gapi.client.sheets loaded.');
        gapi.client
            .init({
                apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                clientId: '0000000000000-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
            })
            .then(function () {
                return gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.get({
                    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
                });
            })
            .then(
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
            );
    });
});
```

My application is running in servlet container and oauth2 is handled at server side. If I want to add authToken how can I do it?

Comment: in my case I got "Forbidden" error when I tried to modified deleted event

Answer (score 3):

You may check in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#403_Forbidden) the reasons why you are getting a `403 Forbidden Error`. It indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response payload (if any).

> If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the server considers them insufficient to grant access.  The client SHOULD NOT automatically repeat the request with the same credentials.  The client MAY repeat the request with new or different credentials.  However, a request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated to the credentials.

***If I want to add authToken how can I do it?***

Follow this documentation about [Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing). You can identify your application using an [OAuth 2.0 token](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#AboutAuthorization).

You may also check on these related threads:

- [Getting 403 forbidden when using the Google Sheets API and a service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071385/getting-403-forbidden-when-using-the-google-sheets-api-and-a-service-account)

  > Make sure that you grant the service account access to the file.
- [Getting a 403 - Forbidden for Google Service Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372453/getting-a-403-forbidden-for-google-service-account)

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error if you are emulating a device within Chrome DevTools.

If you try going through the usual "Sign in with Google" flow, you will see the following error:

```
Error 403: disallowed_useragent

You can’t sign in from this screen because this app doesn’t comply with
Google’s secure browsers policy. If this app has a website, you can open
a web browser and try signing in from there.

You can let the app developer know that this app doesn’t comply with
Google’s secure browsers policy.
```

See [Google's documentation on this topic](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#authorization-errors-disallowed-useragent).

A workaround is to switch to device emulation only *after* going through the authorization flows.